# Neo4j Failed to load csv from local disk (windows 7)

Tags: file, csv, neo4j

I am new to Neo4j and have been trying to load a CSV from my local disk, but without a success.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:/Neo4j/Persons.csv" AS csvLine
CREATE (p:Person { id: toInt(csvLine.id), name: csvLine.name })
```

I am getting the following response and error

```
Couldn't load the external resource at: file:C:/Neo4j/Persons.csv

Neo.TransientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailure
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that the file is in the C:/Neo4j/ directory?

Answer (score 0):

Could not be the perfect solutiuon but might be work for you.

You should try this one:
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM "file:C:/Neo4j/Persons.csv" AS csvLine
CREATE (:PERSONS {id:csvLine.id, name:csvLine.name})

But you should take notice the headers from your Persons.csv file.
Imagine that your file got this header
id | name |
you must use this Cypher code, before the CREATE statment:
FIELDTERMINATOR "|"